# Clean way to truncate result of addition or subtraction

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

When I do addition or subtraction in Verilog, some compilers emit warning.

```
// code example
logic [9 : 0] a, b, c;
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  b <= a + 1;
  c <= a - 1;
end
```

```
// warning example
Warning (13469): Verilog HDL assignment warning at xxx.sv(xxx): truncated value with size 11 to match size of target (10) File: xxx.sv Line: xxx
Warning (13469): Verilog HDL assignment warning at xxx.sv(xxx): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (10) File: xxx.sv Line: xxx
```

I want to find clean way to remove these warnings. I tried two methods:

```
// method 1
b <= (a + 1)[9 : 0];
// method 2
logic [10 : 0] d;
d <= a + 1;
b <= d[9 : 0];
```

I thought the first method would compile, but it was invalid syntax in verilog.
Second method works, but it is too verbose and dirty.
Is there any other clean ways?

Comment: Try `{ a+1 }`. There are no carries inside a concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From IEEE Std 1364-2001.

Page 73:
Table 29—Bit lengths resulting from self-determined expressions:

- Unsized constant number = Same as integer

Page 45:

- NOTE Implementations may limit the maximum size of an integer variable, but they shall at least be 32 bits.

So the warnings you see come from trying to operate one unsized numeric constant (32 bits at least) with a sized variable (10 bits), so the synthesizer warns about the result may overflow.

So, just make sure all your operands have the same size:

Instead of:

```
// code example
logic [9 : 0] a, b, c;
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  b <= a + 1;
  c <= a - 1;
end
```

Do:

```
// code example
logic [9 : 0] a, b, c;
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  b <= a + 10'd1;
  c <= a - 10'd1;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`1` id a 32-bit value. As a result the width of the expression is 32.
The way around is to use a sized value of '1', i.e.

```
b <= a + 1'b1;
c <= b - 1'b1;
```

This can potentially give you an 11-bit result. Carryon bit will be lost. At this point you can do some other tricks. I guess this is the most common one. Use a carry on bit.

```
logic con;
logic[9:0] a,b;
...
{con, a} <= b + 1'b1;
```

You can use a temp variable, as in your example.

In general, verilog standard does allow free truncation or extension of operand widths and no warning is required. Definitely in this case you can ignore the warning or turn it off. I have not seen simulators which would warn about it. Just certain rule in linting tools.

Answer (score 1):

Use curley concatination braces

```
b <= {a + 1}[9 : 0];
```

or change the constant size (which defaults to 32-bits)

```
b <= a + 10'd1;
```